# Stack Exchange site for pedagogy?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange  site for pedagogy?

Pedagogy is very important specially for teachers. Many teachers have the knowledge but you cannot understand anything from their teachings. That's because they don't know pedagogy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a proposal for an [Education](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50826/education) site on Area 51.

> Proposed Q&A site for professional educators and education researchers, K-12 teachers, vocational teachers, school administrators, school faculty, education psychologists, education historians, education theorists and philosophers, non-profit educationists

There is nothing else I can see.

Comment: The proposal has been deleted.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Computer Science Educators](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/) and [Math Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), if your teaching is in one of those fields.

Answer (score -2):

The proposal for Education site was actually deleted. There is an Academia site however, it should be suitable for pedagogical questions since Academia includes teaching naturally. The site for Academia is here https://academia.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Those type of questions need to be narrowly scoped then, given what their [on-topic help page](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says.

Comment: I don't see how a question about for example teaching grammar school level students would be on topic for academia. And no to knock academia, but I have seen too many people in academia who think that "teaching" is hitting their students head on with the theory and leave them to "assistants" to actually get taught. I don't think that "pedagogy" is best served in academia.

Comment: The academia page is primarily for teachers, instructors, and tenured professors whose students are most more than 18 years old.