# What's the target of pedagogical questions

Tags: bug, area-51

I have asked a question about [a Stack Exchange site for pedagogy topics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181485).

I have been referred to [this post](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50826/education).

I enter on this Stack Exchange, and I ask my pedagogical question which title is *[What is the best pedagogical Map items (definition, note, theory, etc.) for a quick review?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10497/what-is-the-best-pedagogical-map-items-definition-note-theory-for-a-quick-re)*. I was surprised when my question was closed as well as I receieve a vote negatively. I do want to ask again: Is there a Stack Exchange target for pedagogical questions?

Comment: You don't understand how area51 works. It is a place to create new site, not the site itself. Currently, the site is still being defined and may be created in the future. You should probably take your question elsewhere, since SE has yet to have a site where your question would fit.

Comment: Please read the Area51 FAQ to understand what the site is about and how you can get involved: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: @Bart I laughed thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between a site (a place where you can ask questions) and a *proposal* (part of the process for building the community for a site).

Area 51 is about *proposals*. It's how we *create* sites. Discussion questions there are about the act of creating a site, either generally or specific to a certain proposal. You would ask about whether pedagogical questions are on-topic for the Education proposal. But you would not actually *ask* one.

The *Education* proposal is still pre-beta, so you can't ask questions there.